# VBAを使いExcelのテーブルからYamlを出力することはできますか？

Tags: excel, vba

掲題の通りです。

ExcelのテーブルをJSONに変換する記事は見つけられるのですがYamlに変換する情報は見つけられませんでした。
ご存知の方がいらしたらご教示頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1):

JSONはYAMLのサブセットなので、JSON出力ができるならYAML出力もできているのでは？と言いたいところですが、YAMLらしい(?)YAMLを出力したいということですね。

JSON同様YAMLもただの文字列ですから、「出力することができない」なんてことはありません。ひたすら文字列結合を行うだけです。

ごく簡単な例を挙げると、例えば次のようになります。

```
Sub ToYAML()
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim result As String

    For r = 2 To 6
        result = result & "- "
        For c = 1 To 3
            result = result & Cells(1, c).Value & ": " & Cells(r, c).Value & vbCrLf & "  "
        Next c
        result = Left(result, Len(result) - 2) ' 末尾の余分な "  " を取り除く
    Next r

    Debug.Print result
End Sub
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

対象とする範囲、ValueなのかTextなのか、クォートの有無、出力方法、等は質問に書かれていないので適当です。必要に応じて調整してください。